# Problema SetOnTouchListener en un WebView

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

Estoy intentando hacer un setOnClickListener sobre un WebView. Dicho WebView carga un reproductor de vídeo, por lo que al pulsar sobre el aparecen los controles del vídeo, pero claro, esto pertenece al propio comportamiento del reproductor que está siendo cargado.

Quiero que al pulsar sobre el WebView me aparezca una barra arriba con un botón de retroceso, uno de información, pero esto es lo de menos. El problema es que dicha pantalla es fullscreen entonces los botones de navegación y demás desaparecen, para que aparezcan unicamente debo deslizar y todo bien. El problema es que cuando deslizo para mostrar dichos botones de navegación, aparecen los botones, pero también detecta como si hubiera pulsado en el WebView y me abre la barra de arriba cuando esto no debería pasar, solamente debería ocurrir al pulsar dentro del WebView. Estos son los métodos de mi clase que maneja esto:

```
private fun showTopMenuBack() {
        playerTopMenuBack.show()
        if (!isClickedOtherTime) {
            runnable = Runnable {
                playerTopMenuBack.hide()
                isClickedOtherTime = false
            }
            handlerTopMenu?.postDelayed(runnable, DELAY_MILLIS_SHOWING_BACK_MENU)
        } else {
            handlerTopMenu?.removeCallbacks(runnable)
            playerTopMenuBack.hide()
        }
    }

override fun onTouch(v: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        val isDoubleClick = isClickTwoTimes(lastClickTime)
        if (event?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            hideTopMenuWhenClickedAgain()
            if (isDoubleClick) {
                return isDoubleClick
            } else {
                lastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
            }
        }
        return v.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

private fun hideTopMenuWhenClickedAgain() {
        isClickedOtherTime = if (!isClickedOtherTime) {
            showTopMenuBack()
            true
        } else {
            showTopMenuBack()
            false
        }
    }
```

Se que el problema está en el onTouchListener, ya que está detectando cualquier toque que haya en la pantalla sea cual sea, pero no se como debería ponerlo para que solamente detecte cuando pulso en ella.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que esto te va a solucionar el problema:

```
override fun onTouch(v: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {   
    val isDoubleClick = isClickTwoTimes(lastClickTime)
    if (event?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        hideTopMenuWhenClickedAgain()
        if (!isDoubleClick) {
            lastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
        }
        return isDoubleClick
    }
    return v.onTouchEvent(event) //Cuando se ejecuta este v.onTouchEvent() es cuando se produce el problema, por eso en caso de que sea ACTION_UP siempre hay un raturn.
}
```